# Проблема с выводом функции python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Реализую вывод из функции, использующей цикл.

```
def deadhosts():
   up = "All devices is up"
   f = os.popen('curl \'http://xxxxxxx')
   now = f.read()
   l = list(now.split('\''))
   if not now == "":
       m = 1
       while m < len(l):
        res = l[m]
        m += 4
        pr = print(res)
       return(pr)
   else:
        return(up)
```

Есть некая ссылка, результат которой я получаю с помощью программы *curl*, результат мне необходимо разделить на отдельные элементы списка и вывести их с помощью цикла. Все работает корректно, кроме самого вывода.

Если использую функцию `print()`, то результат пустой. Если функцию `return`, то цикл на первом же элементе заканчивается.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Overcomplicated, как говорится, у вас код. Для начала, вы точно понимаете что делает `return` и `print`?

`return` возвращает значение из функции и прерывает её исполнение, т.е.:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b

c = f(1, 2)
c  # 3
```

`print` просто выводит значение в консоль и ничего не прерывает, при этом она ничего не возвращает, точнее возвращает `None`, в результате `pr = print(res)` выведет значение переменной `res` в консоль и присвоит переменной `pr` значение `None`, второе действие явно бессмысленное.

Зачем вы так хитро используйте переменную `m`? Вам действительно нужен каждый четвертый элемент списка, начиная со второго?

Чтобы вывести на экран все элементы списка:

```
for item in l:
    print(item)
```

Если нужно выводить элементы следуя вашей логике с `m`, то проще сделать так:

```
for i in range(1, len(l), 4):
    print(l[i])
```

Вы можете также преобразовать функцию в генератор заменив `return` на `yield`, но это, вероятно, слишком сложный концепт для начала.

Немного общих рекомендаций:

- Используйте отступы в 4 пробела
- `return pr` вместо `return(pr)`
- `if now:` вместо `if not now == "":`

Comment: Павел, спасибо за ответ. Я понимаю назначение return и print, но не понимаю как с их помощью решить проблему. Мне действительно необходимо выводить результат каждого 4 элемента, начиная со второго. И как вы правильно заметили, моя функция выводит в результате только None, хотя print в консоль печатает все нужные мне элементы. Я не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы функция выдала в результате именно перечень нужных элементов? Конструкция `for i in range(1, len(l), 4): return(l[i])` возвращает только первый элемент

Comment: Вам нужно вернуть из функции список? Распишите конкретно что вы хотите где видеть, иначе не совсем понятно, чего вы ожидаете. Вернуть список можно через `return l[1::4]`

Comment: Да, результатом должен быть список элементов. В итоге получилось так : `f = os.popen('curl \'http://xxxx'')
now = f.read()
l = list(now.split('\''))

def deadhosts():
   if now:  return(l[1::4])` Далее requests.post отправляет результат deadhosts(), но отправляет он почему то только первый элемент списка

Answer (score 1):

`print()` функция всегда возвращает `None` (бессмысленно присваивать это возвращаемое значение какой-либо переменной и возвращать его вверх по стэку).

---

Не нужно создавать внешний процес, чтобы сделать HTTP запрос в Питоне, можно использовать `urlopen(..)` вместо `os.popen('curl..')`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ast
from urllib.request import urlopen

def deadhosts():
    with urlopen('http://xxxxxxx') as response:
        data = response.read().decode() # [('10.177.0.9', 5, '3'), ...]
    hosts = ast.literal_eval(data) 
    return [ip for ip, *rest in hosts] # -> ['10.177.0.9', '10.177.0.7']
```

`ast.literal_eval()` позволяет распознать Питон константы (безопаснее чем `eval()`):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[('10.177.0.9', 5, '3'), ('10.177.0.7', 5, '1')]")
[('10.177.0.9', 5, '3'), ('10.177.0.7', 5, '1')]
```

Лучше использовать JSON формат в этом случае (более переносим и быстрее):

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[["10.177.0.9", 5, "3"], ["10.177.0.7", 5, "1"]]')
[['10.177.0.9', 5, '3'], ['10.177.0.7', 5, '1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

А что возвращает now = f.read()?

**Update.**

Вы, наверное, хотели что-то вроде такого сделать:

```
def deadhosts():
   f = os.popen('curl \'http://xxxxxxx')
   now = f.read()
   if now:
       l = now.split('\'')
       m = 1
       result_list = list()
       while m < len(l):
           res = l[m]
           result_list.append(res)
           print(res)

           m += 4

       return result_list
   else:
        up = "All devices is up"
        print(up)
```

Если что-то пришло (строка не пуста), делим строку по разделителю, и начиная со второго элемента (m=1), каждый четвёртый нужно вывести, если ничего не пришло, то все хорошо.

Правильно?

> К сожалению код возвращает только первый элемент списка - 10.177.0.9, хотя должно быть два - [('10.177.0.9', 5, '3'), ('10.177.0.7', 5, '1')]. Да, согласен, вид в котором пребывает эта строка очень неудобен, но так возвращает результат система, которую я опрашиваю. – psiisyapk

Мой код вернул 2 ip адреса. return должен быть после цикла идти, а не внутри его, тогда проблем нет:

```
10.177.0.9
10.177.0.7
['10.177.0.9', '10.177.0.7']
```

И я бы на вашем месте все-таки преобразовал строку в объект питона или разобрал регуляркой, пример:

С регулярками:

```
import re

pattern_ip = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})')

def deadhosts():
    # f = os.popen('curl \'http://xxxxxxx')
    # now = f.read()
    now = "[('10.177.0.3', 5, '3'), ('10.177.0.7', 5, '1')]"

    match = pattern_ip.findall(now)
    if match:
        print('Match: {}'.format(match))
        return match

    up = "All devices is up"
    print(up)
```

Через преобразование в объект питона:

```
import ast

def deadhosts():
    # f = os.popen('curl \'http://xxxxxxx')
    # now = f.read()
    now = "[('10.177.0.3', 5, '3'), ('10.177.0.7', 5, '1')]"

    if now:
        obj = ast.literal_eval(now)
        print(obj)

        ip_list = [val[0] for val in obj]
        print('IP list: {}'.format(ip_list))
        return ip_list

    up = "All devices is up"
    print(up)
```

Comment: f.read() возвращает результат команды curl в виде списка

Comment: Вы хотели сказать в виде строки (str)?
А какое там значение возвращается?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы всегда можете оставлять комментарии под **своими** вопросами и ответами. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/60053)

Comment: @Streletz, вот именно, что я не мог комментировать из-за нехватки репутации, поэтому и задал в виде ответа на вопрос

Comment: @gil9red, тем не менее в качестве ответа стоит публиковать только то, что является решением проблемы. ruSO, это не совсем форум в привычном смысле этого слова. А, насчёт репутации. Заработайте необходимое количество баллов (в данный момент, если не ошибаюсь, требуется 50) и у Вас появится возможность комментировать не только свои, но и чужие сообщения.

Comment: Прошу прощения, now = f.read() возвращает строку. А уже с помощью split получают список.

Comment: @psiisyapk, не извиняйтесь, и перефразурую, приведите, пожалуйста, пришедшую строку и что из этой строки вы хотите вытащить -- так всегда проще разобраться

Comment: `>>> f = os.popen('curl \'http://xxxxxx'')
>>> now = f.read()
>>> l = list(now.split('\''))
>>> print(l)
['[(', '10.177.0.9', ', 5, ', '3', ')]']
>>> print(l[1])
10.177.0.9` Вот список элементов (каждый 4ый начиная с первого) мне и нужен в выводе

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, добавив код, проверьте его

Comment: Т.е. у нас приходят строки такого вида: "[('10.177.0.9', 5, '3')]"
И мы вытаскиваем из них, например, ip-адреса. Можно было проще сделать, чем разделять по одинарным кавычкам, например, вытаскивать регулярками

Да и эта строка имеет такой вид, что так и хочется ее преобразовать в питоничий объект:

p = eval("[('10.177.0.9', 5, '3')]")
print(p, type(p), p[0][0])

Получим:
[('10.177.0.9', 5, '3')] <class 'list'> 10.177.0.9

Comment: К сожалению код возвращает только первый элемент списка - 10.177.0.9, хотя должно быть два - `[('10.177.0.9', 5, '3'), ('10.177.0.7', 5, '1')]`. Да, согласен, вид в котором пребывает эта строка очень неудобен, но так возвращает результат система, которую я опрашиваю.

Comment: Пока что получилось сделать в таком виде : `def deadhosts():
 up = "All devices is up"
 f = os.popen('curl \'http://x:x@xxxx')
 now = f.read()
 l = list(now.split('\''))
 if now:
        return('Devices are out of service: '+'\n'+str(l[1::4]).replace(', ', '\n'))
        
 else:
       return up`

Результат в виде : 
`Devices are out of service: 
['10.177.0.9'
'10.177.0.7']`

Не сказал бы что красиво, но результат корректен

Comment: @psiisyapk: не помещайте решение в комментариях. Вы можете [опубликовать его в виде ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (чтобы можно было бы за него голосовать, комментрировать и чтобы другие посетители могли его найти).